# Retrieving a data in database and display it to notification in broadcastreceiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite, android-notifications

i want select all the data in sqlite database with two condition, "Date" anda "Time". Format for Date is "dd/mm/yyy or 01/12/2014" and Time is "hh:mm or 17:15".

Bellow is the code in my databasehandler

public List getMessageToSent(String Date, String Time) {

```
    List<TestSaving> savingList = new ArrayList<TestSaving>();

    String query = "Select " + KEY_ROWID + "," + KEY_CONTACT_NAME + ","
            + KEY_CONTACT_NO + "," + KEY_CONTACT_MESSAGE + ","
            + KEY_CONTACT_PICTURE + " from testsaving where "
            + KEY_CONTACT_DATESEND + " = " + Date + " AND "
            + KEY_CONTACT_TIMESEND + " = " + Time + " order by "
            + KEY_CONTACT_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TestSaving testSave = new TestSaving();
            testSave.set_contact_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            testSave.set_contact_name(cursor.getString(1));
            testSave.set_contact_no(cursor.getString(2));
            testSave.set_contact_message(cursor.getString(3));
            testSave.set_contact_picture(cursor.getBlob(4));

            savingList.add(testSave);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return savingList;
}
```

and bellow is my code in BroadCastReceiver Class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(context);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Date = new StringBuilder().append(Utility.utilTime(day)).append("/")
            .append(Utility.utilTime(month)).append("/")
            .append(Utility.utilTime(year));

    Time = new StringBuilder().append(Utility.utilTime(hour)).append("/")
            .append(Utility.utilTime(minute));

    List<TestSaving> testSavings = db.getMessageToSent(Date.toString(),
            Time.toString());

    for (TestSaving ts : testSavings) {
        String log = "contact_id:" + ts.get_contact_id()
                + " ,contact_name: " + ts.get_contact_name()
                + " ,contact_no: " + ts.get_contact_no()
                + " ,contact_message: " + ts.get_contact_message()
                + " ,contact_picture: " + ts.get_contact_picture();

        Log.d("Result: ", log);


        Notification(context, Date + " dan " + Time);
    }

}
```

i don't get error when i'm looking at the Log. Can Some one, tell me how to fix it?

P.s the receiver works fine with dummy data,

Comment: Search [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for Time Strings, to get a list of the valid datetime formats in SQLite.

Comment: can i select the data from database by just comparing using  "=" in sqlite? like select * from Table1 where column1 = '12/12/2014'?

Comment: **NO**. Not in **that** format. The right format is `2014-12-12`

Comment: oke, but the data type should be Text, Real, or Integer?

Comment: TEXT. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: despite the mistake from sqlite, how about the code? is there something wrong in it?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks dude for your help, problem solved. just Need to go deeper to code :)